# Preview next post

Tags: blogger

I would like to preview the next post at the post at the bottom of each item. The aim is to increase number of page views per visitor by having them view a snippet of the next blog post, and clicking on it if interested.

I am wondering the best way to go about the issue to get the title of the next post and a preview of the body (summary).

Should I use expression on the posts or the feeds. The code should also be efficient so that it doesn't loop unnecessarily through all items.

This is for Google's Blogger service.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little please? I don't fully understand. Are you wanting a Stack Overflow styled post preview under the textarea?

Comment: I edited the question, hope it is more clear?

Comment: You could assigned each post entry with a timestamp, then when viewing a post, create a new mysql query which fetches the next entry, either by comparing unique ID's or a timestamp. Then just fetch the new results title and post, then use substr(); on the post to strip the post to a certain amount of characters such as - $post = substr($post, 0, 100); echo("$post"); - That way you will see only a snippet of the next entry. Sorry if I've misunderstood!

Comment: well, i am looking for a blogger specific solution, ie for Google's blogspot

Comment: Ah, apologies, I thought it was for a custom blog system. I'm afraid I've never used Blogspot before so I'm unsure on it's features, sorry! :(

Comment: maybe there is a way to do it with the template system, but the best I can think of is to use the API to figure out what the next post is, but I think that will be somewhat ugly and not quick

Comment: Do you  have a link to the complete API with documentation, because that appears to be the only way for now.

Comment: Is it okay for the preview to be loaded via javascript?

Comment: I guess that will be ok, however it may lock out a number of mobile devices.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but this post is still getting viewers, so I thought I would answer it.

As far as displaying the post title instead of the next and previous posts (also known as "older post" and "newer post"), copy-paste the following code above the "/head"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">       </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var olderLink = $("a.blog-pager-older-link").attr("href");
$("a.blog-pager-older-link").load(olderLink+" h3:first", function() {
var olderLinkTitle = $("a.blog-pager-older-link:first").text();
$("a.blog-pager-older-link").text(olderLinkTitle);
});
var newerLink = $("a.blog-pager-newer-link").attr("href");
$("a.blog-pager-newer-link").load(newerLink+" h3:first", function() {
var newerLinkTitle = $("a.blog-pager-newer-link:first").text();
$("a.blog-pager-newer-link").text(newerLinkTitle);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Locate '`<b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'>`' in your HTML.
put following code right after the the above code.

```
<b:includable id='nextprev'>
<div class='blog-pager' id='blog-pager'>
<b:if cond='data:newerPageUrl'>
<span id='blog-pager-newer-link'>
<a class='blog-pager-newer-link' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-newer-link&quot;' expr:title='data:newerPageTitle'><data:newerPageTitle/></a>
</span>
</b:if>

<b:if cond='data:olderPageUrl'>
<span id='blog-pager-older-link'>
<a class='blog-pager-older-link' expr:href='data:olderPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-older-link&quot;' expr:title='data:olderPageTitle'><data:olderPageTitle/></a>
</span>
</b:if>

<b:if cond='data:blog.homepageUrl != data:blog.url'>
<a class='home-link' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><data:homeMsg/></a>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:newerPageUrl'>
<a class='home-link' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><data:homeMsg/></a>
</b:if>
</b:if>

</div>
<div class='clear'/>
</b:includable>
```

It should work.

Comment: I thought this is the standard blogger code for next and previous page. What I am looking for is code to show a preview of the next post  under each post view.

Comment: _What I am looking for is code to show a preview of the next post under each post view_ **Blogger already has older post and newer post links under each post. Do u want to show thumbnails of those post?**

Comment: yeah,I want some text, probably a paragraph or two, or truncation at a certain number of characters, say 300 of the next post, with a readmore that links to the post.